# How do I add markers to a Mapbox map outside of a Mapbox event?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

All the examples I've seen for adding a marker to the map show the marker being added in the "onMapReady" callback or the "onMapClick" callback. I have an app that periodically finds the user's latitude and longitude and I want to add a marker to the map when the lat and lng updates. This happens outside of the previously mentioned callbacks. How would I do that? I need access to the Style object of the map but it's only accesible inside the callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason these callbacks (in particular `onMapReady`) are used in all the examples is to ensure that the mapboxMap objects's style has been loaded by the time you attempt to modify it - if it isn't there is the potential for some asynchronous weirdness as the map renders.

I would recommend you still include the logic for adding the periodic lat/lon coordinates as markers within the `onMapReady` callback.

---

⚠️ Disclaimer: I currently work for Mapbox ⚠️

Comment: thanks @riastrad.  if onMapReady get's called only once when the map is loaded, how would you recommend I make periodic updates to the map?Maybe set up a listener of some sort?